# Wordpress setup latency on Azure

Tags: mysql, wordpress, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a Wordpress environment setup on Azure.

Front end is on WebApp (Size is S2 - 2 cores & 3.5 GB RAM) whilst DB is on 2 replicated Classic Virtual Machines (Size F2 - 2 cores / 4 GB Memory).

We also tried connecting the web app to the VMs over a point-to-site VPN which in a nutshell is a VPN from 1 Azure service (WebApp) to another (VMs), so ultimately connection is still being made over the internet.

I'm looking for ways to improve network latency between Azure's WebApp and Virtual Machines.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, If your trying to "improve" the network latency then you have a issue somewhere else. Please provide more details on your latency issue.

You should be pushing towards the ARM stuff now. If you want to improve the performance then you can **try using azure service fabric.**